# Count occurrences of strings in a field, contained in another field. MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im very new to MS Access and I'm struggling a bit.

I have a table of postcodes that look like this:

```
+-----------+
| Postcode  |
+-----------+
| Wa13 657  |
| eC2B 984  |
| eq8 987   |
+-----------+
```

And another table with 10 fields.

One of the fields is `pickup address` which has entries that look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|              pickup address              |
+------------------------------------------+
| 69, example entry road, London, wa13 657 |
| 87, example entry road, London, eC2B 984 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I'm looking to count the number of times that each `postcode` is spotted within the `pickup address` field.

The postcode has to be full, i.e. partial entries such as `eC2B` should not be counted.

So firstly I'd like to get a total count. If possible, secondly I'd like to vary this by date ranges, which are stored in separate fields in the second table.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: To make this more complicated the postcode is at different locations in some of the records, i.e. sometimes its at the front sometimes at the end. There are 2.5 million records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join with calculated join criteria:

```
select p.postcode, count(*)
from Postcodes p inner join Addresses a on instr(a.[pickup address],p.postcode) > 0
group by p.postcode
```

Change `Postcodes` to the name of the table containing your postcodes, and `Addresses` to the name of the table containing your pickup addresses (and change the `postcode` and `pickup address` field names as appropriate if necessary).

If you wish to further filter the results by date, simply add a `WHERE` clause:

```
select p.postcode, count(*)
from Postcodes p inner join Addresses a on instr(a.[pickup address],p.postcode) > 0
where a.date >= #2018-12-06#
group by p.postcode
```

(Change `date` to the name of your date field; you'll need to provide more information about the structure of your data if this date should reference another field).

**Note that this type of query cannot be displayed by the MS Access Query Designer and can only be viewed as SQL.**

Comment: Lee - thank you so much. This worked wonderfully. How would i go about adding dates into this, I have another column in the addresses table and would like to be able to vary the query with different date ranges. Thanks.

Comment: @j_henry You're welcome; I have updated my answer above.